# Fetch return undefined in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I'm trying to use WordPress API with react, but it returns id instead of the tag name, so I'm trying to fetch the tag name with another API call. but it keeps returning undefined. When I add return before fetch inside getCategory() it just errors out.

```
componentDidMount() {
const URL =
  'https://public-api.wordpress.com/wp/v2/sites/sitename/posts/';

  fetch(URL)
  .then(res => res.json())
  .then(posts => {

    const post = posts.map(post => {
      return {
        ...post,
        categories: this.getCategory(...post.categories)
      };
    });

    this.setState({ posts: post });

    console.log(post);
  })
  .catch(err => console.log(err));
  }

  getCategory(id) {
   const URL = `https://public-api.wordpress.com/wp/v2/sites/sitename/categories/${id}`;

fetch(URL)
  .then(data => data.json())
  .then(res => res.name)
 }
```

Comment: A possible bug is that your `getCategory` expects a single id, but you are spreading all the `post.categories` there.

Comment: It's an array but with one value @LyoshaKorogoda

Comment: Ok so I commented out the setState and added return to fetch inside the getCategory() function now I return a promise for value categories, but when I call .then after this.getCategory(...post.categories) it's still a promise?

Comment: Mind you that `getCategory` has no `return` value, and even if you return the `fetch`, you are returning a `Promise`. Also, you might want to edit out your URLs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, your problem is that you're setting the state before the `fetch` in `getCategory` resolves. To address that, you can await for its result --

```
componentDidMount() {
  const URL = 'https://public-api.wordpress.com/wp/v2/sites/sitename/posts/';  
  fetch(URL)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(posts => {
      return Promise.all(posts.map(async post => {
        return {
          ...post,
          categories: await this.getCategory(...post.categories)
        };
      }));
    })
    .then(posts => this.setState({ posts: posts }))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}

getCategory(id) {
  const URL = `https://public-api.wordpress.com/wp/v2/sites/sitenameress.com/categories/${id}`;

  return fetch(URL)
    .then(data => data.json())
    .then(res => res.name)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

first: getCategory method returns nothing.

```
getCategory(id) {
   const URL = `https://public-api.wordpress.com/wp/v2/sites/sitename/categories/${id}`;

return fetch(URL).then(data => data.json()).then(res => res.name);

}
```

second: when you run setState method (probably) http request for category (getCategory) is still running, so categories are not set yet.

you should use [Promise.all()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) method to be sure all http requests are done before you call setState method.

Answer (score 0):

Referencing @lyosha-korogoda's answer, if you can't use `async/await`, try something like this instead:

```
componentDidMount() {
  const URL = 'https://public-api.wordpress.com/wp/v2/sites/<YOUR_WORDPRESS_URL>/posts/';

  fetch(URL)
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(posts => {
      this.getCategory(...post.categories).then(category => {
        const post = posts.map(post => {
          return {
            ...post,
            categories: category
          };
        });
        this.setState({ posts: post });
        console.log(post);
      })
    })
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
}

getCategory(id) {
  const URL = `https://public-api.wordpress.com/wp/v2/sites/<YOUR_WORDPRESS_URL>/categories/${id}`;

  return fetch(URL)
    .then(data => data.json())
    .then(res => res.name)
}
```

Note how I moved `getCategory` out and wrapping the `map` into it's `then` block. Honestly the code could be cleaner, but just to show how it works.

As to why your `fetch` returns `undefined`, first it's because your `getCategory(id)` did not `return` anything. And second, it's simply because how JavaScript's asynchronous nature really, so your `const post` doesn't have value because `getCategory(id)` has not finished at that time.